# Change div id and property when window size change in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

My current code is

```
<div id="column-left">
     Test
</div>
```

When the window size is smaller than 640px, how can I change it as:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-position="left">
     Test
</div>
```

data-role="panel" is jquerymobile code. The question is focusing on how we can add the data-role="panel" attribute to the div. Thanks!

You may test your code in http://jsbin.com/wakagumu/11/edit. If it success, the test "FIRST" will disappear after changing the id="column-left" to data-role="panel" id="left-panel".

Comment: Are you using jQM 1.3.2?

Comment: Yes it is. but I think adding the data-role attribute is not related to JQM version.

Comment: It's related, because there are different ways in _initializing_ jQM widgets manually.

Comment: icic! Please help and try! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(this).width() < 640) {
        var myDiv = $('#column-left');
        if (myDiv.length > 0) {
            myDiv.attr('id', 'left-panel').data('role', 'panel').data('position', 'left');
        }
    } else {
        var myDiv = $('#left-panel');
        if (myDiv.length > 0) {
            myDiv.attr('id', 'column-left').data('role', '').data('position', '');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code is not working. However, I found you may have the right way to add the data-role attribute to div. Would you mind combining the code under http://jsbin.com/wakagumu/8/edit (This code can change upon resize, but cannot add data-role attribute to div.) and try?

Answer (score 0):

Changing *attributes* won't convert a div into a *panel*, you need to *initialize* it manually. In jQuery Mobile 1.3, you should use `.trigger("pagecreate")` when appending a *panel* dynamically in order to *initialize* it.

The below solution creates a *panel* and moves *content* div's elements when *page*'s width is small; and it removes *panel* and returns *content* div's element to their original position. Also, it creates a button inside *header* to open the *panel*. It can be used in any *page events* as well as on window's `throttledresize` and `orientationchange`.

```
$(window).on("throttledresize", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.activePage;
    if ($(window).width() < 500 && activePage.find("[data-role=panel]").length === 0) {
       /* create button */
        var button = $("<a/>", {
            "data-role": "button",
                "data-icon": "bars",
                "id": "panelBtn",
                "data-theme": "e",
            class: "ui-btn-left"
        }).text("Panel");
        /* add click listener to open panel 
           and append it to header         */
        activePage.find(".ui-header").append($(button).on("click", function () {
            $("#left-panel").panel("open");
        }));

        /* save menu */
        var menu = $("#menu");
        /* create a panel 
           append menu
           create page    */
        activePage.prepend($("<div/>", {
            id: "left-panel",
                "data-role": "panel",
                "data-position": "left",
                "data-display": "push"
        }).append($("<div/>", {
            class: "ui-panel-inner"
        }).append(menu))).trigger("pagecreate");
    }

    if ($(window).width() > 500 && activePage.find("[data-role=panel]").length === 1) {
        /* remove panel and button
           return menu to content div */
        if (activePage.hasClass("ui-page-panel-open")) {
            activePage.find("[data-role=panel]").panel("close").on("panelclose", function () {
                var menu1 = activePage.find("[data-role=panel] #menu");
                activePage.find("[data-role=content]").append(menu1);
                activePage.find("[data-role=panel]").remove();
                activePage.find("#panelBtn").remove();
                activePage.trigger("pagecreate");
            });
        } else {
            var menu1 = activePage.find("[data-role=panel] #menu");
            activePage.find("[data-role=content]").append(menu1);
            activePage.find("[data-role=panel]").remove();
            activePage.find("#panelBtn").remove();
            activePage.trigger("pagecreate");
        }
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/64a9R/)**

Comment: It seems a little bit complex to me. Is it possible for adding an if condition to show that two html respectively?

Comment: @user2699714 true, it's complicated, this is what you wanted. What do you mean by "show that two html"?

Comment: if width > 640 show <div id="column-left">, else, show <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-position="left">

Comment: @user2699714 in this case you have to insert a panel and a button, hide/show button based on width. is this what you want?

Comment: Your code is what I want, but it's a little bit complicated. Is it possible you can simply the code?

Comment: @user2699714 it looks complicated because I'm removing panel when screen width is wide, you can use the first block of code if you want. Unfortunately you dont have much rep to invite for chat to explain to you.

Comment: @user2699714 I will explain to you what's going on in my code.