# Show hide the list by radio button in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

In the following code, how can I
- If I click all, it will show both buy and rent
- If I click buy, it will show buy (Rangeslider) only
- If I click rent, it will show rent (Rangeslider) only

```
    <div class="box-filter">
        <!---------------------------------------- Filtering Start ---------------------------------------->
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false"  data-theme="d">
                <li>
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                        <legend></legend>
                        <input name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1a" type="radio" checked="checked" value="">
                        <label for="radio-choice-h-1a">All</label>
                        <input name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1b" type="radio" value="1">
                        <label for="radio-choice-h-1b">Buy</label>
                        <input name="radio-choice-h-1" id="radio-choice-h-1c" type="radio" value="2">
                        <label for="radio-choice-h-1c">Rent</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </li>
            <!-- Buy Start -->
                <li id="rangeslider_buy">
                    <div data-role="rangeslider" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="range-1a">Buy</label>
                        <input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="2000" value="0" type="range" />
                        <label for="range-1b">Buy</label>
                        <input name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="2000" value="2000" type="range" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            <!-- Buy End -->
            <!-- Rent Start -->     
                <li id="rangeslider_rent">
                    <div data-role="rangeslider" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="range-2a">Rent</label>
                        <input name="range-2a" id="range-2a" min="0" max="50000" value="0" type="range" />
                        <label for="range-2b">Rent</label>
                        <input name="range-2b" id="range-2b" min="0" max="50000" value="50000" type="range" />
                    </div>
                </li>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer not ever have `if` 's or `switch` 's and I would like to **re-use** the code as much as possible, so I would do as:

```
$(function(){

  $(".radio-selectors input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    // get selected radio area
    var radioType = $(this).attr("data-area");        
    // hide all
    $(".area-all").hide();
    // show correct
    $(".area-" + radioType).show();
  });

});
```

---

with JQuery Mobile Suggestions rule about hide and show:

```
$(function(){

  $(".radio-selectors input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    // get selected radio area
    var radioType = $(this).attr("data-area");        
    // hide all
    $(".area-all").addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
    // show correct
    $(".area-" + radioType).removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
  });

});
```

new demo: http://jsbin.com/rokohive/3/edit?html,js,output

---

and I would append classes to the HTML code as:

```
<ul ... class="radio-selectors">

<input id="radio-choice-h-1a" data-area="all" ...
<input id="radio-choice-h-1b" data-area="buy" ...
<input id="radio-choice-h-1c" data-area="rent" ...
```

and

```
<li id="rangeslider_buy" class="area-buy area-all">
<li id="rangeslider_rent" class="area-rent area-all">
```

This way, later, you can simply add more `radio` buttons and more `areas` and you do not have to change the javascript code:

Demo in JsBin: http://jsbin.com/rokohive/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: self-executing `$(function(){});` function and `.ready()` should not be used in jQM to bind events.

Comment: true, but it's an example, and then again the `should`... you need to understand what's going on in the inner guts of code in order to know that in this case, both work properly. Their initialization is to start way more things, in the example code, there is not even a `page` element...

Comment: Agree both answers are great! Balexandre's result is more easy to maintain if it will add more selections in future! Thank you very much both and I added useful for both methods!

Answer (score 2):

> ### Update
>
> In **jQuery Mobile**, it is recommended to use class `ui-screen-hidden` instead of `.show()`/`.hide()` functions, in order not to break elements structure. Also, for better results, *listview* should be **refreshed** after hiding/showing elements.

---

Listen to `change` event fired on `type=radio`. Give each radio button a *value* and accordingly show/hide elements.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    $("[type=radio]").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            if ($(this).val() == "all") { /* All */
                $("#rangeslider_buy, #rangeslider_rent").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");

            }
            if ($(this).val() == "buy") { /* Buy */
                $("#rangeslider_buy").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");
                $("#rangeslider_rent").addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
            }
            if ($(this).val() == "rent") { /* Rent */
                $("#rangeslider_buy").addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
                $("#rangeslider_rent").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");

            }
            $("listview_ID").listview("refresh");
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/xaq27/)**

Comment: just a heads up to improve your way of codding: You should always write code that is easy reusable. Currently, your code, if we need that functionality in other parts of the application, we need to either copy/paste/edit as new method, or keep changing... now [look at my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22144727/28004), you will never need to change anything again...

Comment: @balexandre Thanks for the heads up. 1) I wrote this on purpose to simplify how to achieve the desired results. 2) my code is complied with jQM rules. 3) When I wrote a complicated code on a different question of the same OP, I got this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008851/change-div-id-and-property-when-window-size-change-in-jquerymobile/22020104#comment33600870_22020104).

Comment: **2**: You can simple do the same on my `hide()` and `show()` and use what they suggest (remember that it's a suggestion rule, this case it will do the exact same) **3**: you do complicate a bit, then again, you might have ear before that "less is more", and the code I wrote is here to prove that ;)

Comment: @balexandre compare my demo with yours. Note the UI of shown `li`.

Comment: what are you talking about? did you saw my code addition? I have included your "suggest rule" as well... and remember that you are using an older version of jQM.

Comment: @balexandre 1) I did see it, you forgot to `.listview("refresh")`. 2) the OP is using jQM 1.3.x 3) If you _don't like_ my answer you can simply downvote/flag it :)

Comment: `listView('refresh')` is only needed when you change the contents of a list dynamically, in this case, you are not. I'm doing Jquery mobile apps since version 1.0 beta (used to use jQTouch and even made [plugins for that](https://code.google.com/p/jqtouch-ical/))

Comment: @balexandre also when you hide/show `li` elements within _listview_. listview adds `ui-first-child` and `ui-last-child` to `li`, you need to refresh _listview_ in order to add those classes properly. **Edit** it's more obvious when you use `data-inset="true"`

Comment: @Omar, does this "ui-screen-hidden" apply only for li or for any control

Comment: Agree both answers are great! Balexandre's result is more easy to maintain if it will add more selections in future! Thank you very much both and I added useful for both methods!

Comment: @ScorpionRulz Yes, you can use it on any element. It's simply `display: none;`. When you use `.show()` it adds `display: block;` which could break structure.

Comment: @user2699714 dont forget to _refresh_ listview after hiding elements. Good luck :)

Comment: @Omar should this be to the control which is already displayed, coz I tried it this for the control which was already hiden using "style=display:none" and it didnt worked!

Comment: Thanks Omar! I use Balexandre's method but use addClass("ui-screen-hidden") => jqm rule.

Comment: @ScorpionRulz because inline `style` overrides `.class`. You should use it without inline `style`.

Comment: @user2699714 `$("listviewID").listview("refresh")` is essential to re-enhance listview's UI :)

Comment: @user2699714 forgot to tell you that you're better off listening to `change` not `click`. And use `.on()` to bind events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/4f55k/

```
var $buy = $('#rangeslider_buy'), $rent = $('#rangeslider_rent');

$('#radio-choice-h-1a').click(function () { $buy.add($rent).show() });
$('#radio-choice-h-1b').click(function () { $rent.hide(); $buy.show(); });
$('#radio-choice-h-1c').click(function () { $rent.show(); $buy.hide(); });
```

Animated: http://jsfiddle.net/4f55k/1/